# How do I link a URL from an external provider to my Azure AKS DNS-ZONE to be able to access my website via the url?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns

I have a question about Azure DNS delegation and hope to find the answer here.

What have I done so far?

1. I have created a DNS zone in Azure. This zone is named exactly like my url that I want to associate with the website.
2. I have deposited the nameservers created from the DNS zone with my provider for the url.
   [image]
3. I have created 2 records. Here they are listed:
   [image]
   In my A-Record I have chosen the ip address from the url for my website and in the CNAME record I have chosen the external IP of my Kubernetes cluster.
   [image]

Now to my problem: If I call the web page over the URL of my standard browser then I am indeed directed to the page. However, instead of the URL, the IP address is displayed.

And if I use another browser or PC I get a 404 NotFound page.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how I can solve this problem? I have already contacted the provider of the URL but they don't seem to have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you updated DNS record and nameservers with your provider make sure `A` record should point to the **public IP address of your AKS load balancer:**

```
Name: <your domain name>
Type: A
TTL: 3600
Value: <AKS load balancer IP address>
```

The `CNAME` record should point to the DNS name of your AKS load balancer.

```
Name: www
Type: CNAME
TTL: 3600
Value: <AKS load balancer DNS name>
```

You can check your public Ip address like below:

[image]

Check the DNS record is created by external DNS:

```
az network dns record-set a list -g <MyResourceGroup> -z <www.mysite.com>
```

[image]

You can read the logs to get more information what is happening in the external DNS pod using below command:

```
kubectl logs <Name of the pod> -n <Name of the namespace>
```

It will detect if any new service or new ingress created of if they have been updated so it will have synchronized to the traffic. it will create or update the A record with public Ip address for your service.

[image]

***References:***

[docker-kubernetes-course/61_external_dns at main · HoussemDellai/docker-kubernetes-course · GitHub](https://github.com/HoussemDellai/docker-kubernetes-course/tree/main/61_external_dns) by *HoussemDellai*

[External-DNS with Azure Kubernetes Service and Azure DNS · Thorsten Hans' blog (thorsten-hans.com)](https://www.thorsten-hans.com/external-dns-azure-kubernetes-service-azure-dns/) by Thorsten Hans